# Remove Whitespaces before Capital Letters using re

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

It's quite simple but I'm relatively new using Regex. I would like to change the following string:

"  I love cats", "  I love dogs"
"I love cats", "I love dogs"

I just want to know the setup for removing spaces before any sort of pattern. In this instance, a Capital Letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion combined with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re 

s = ' I love cats'
re.sub(r'''^         # match beginning of string
           \s+       # match one or more instances of whitespace
           (?=[A-Z]) # positive lookahead assertion of an uppercase character
        ''','',s,flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

And to show you that the whitespace is *not* removed before a lowercase letter:

```
s = ' this is a test'
re.sub(r'^\s+(?=[A-Z])','',s)
```

Result:

```
' this is a test'
```